# How to output the excel with filters enabled on columns in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a crystal report where I need to mail the users the data in the excel as an attachment but with the condition that filters are enabled in each columns of the excel report .
If I have 10 columns in excel , user doesn't want to apply filter explicitly rather they want the filter already present so that they can filter based on any column .
If there is another better way of filtering the data on user side please suggest that too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this from within Crystal reports. You can write an application, which will export the report to Excel, open the Excel file and add a filter.

There is a free version of R-Tag, which supports this feature. You can see it demonstrated here: http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/Preview_RTagAndBOE.aspx
Use the menu to jump to "Advanced report extensions" or go to position 5:26

If this works for you, here is the link to the free edition:
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx